# c#, visual-studio, интеграция отладки в код

Tags: c#, visual-studio, отладка

1. Существуют ли наработанные подходы к интеграции отладки в код?
2. Если существуют, то какие?
3. Если не существует, то есть ли какие-нибудь идеи?

Узнал, что в `visual-studio` можно жестко прописывать в коде точки останова. Пришла идея объединить вызов точки останова из кода с выводом в `output`. Причем, с выводом названия метода и номера строки. То, что получилось напишу в ответе. Сразу помогло найти какие-то ошибки в своем коде.

4. Целесообразно ли вообще использовать подобный подход?
5. Целесообразно ли повсеместно закладывать подобный подход на этапе до отладки?
6. Чего не достает в описании концепции или как можно ее усовершенствовать или что лишнее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из моего другого ответа можно выбрать только метод `WriteLine(string)`, который сам добавляет в конце строчки имя класса и метода - инфу из *StackTrace*-a (так же выбрать сопутствующие другие методы).

Далее поверх вызова этого *WriteLine* поставить обыкновенную студийную точку останова.

Тогда и получается реализация задумки, то есть, при остановке в отладке можно посмотреть *StackTrace*, а так же по логам в *output* тоже что-то можно посмотреть.

Answer (score 1):

Отчасти основано на вызове `Debugger.Break()`. Если кратко, то использовать можно так:

> ```
>            if (this.Debug())
>                Debugger.Break();
> ```

---

Механизм:

Интерфейсом `IWithBreakpoints` могут быть наделены классы, чтобы можно было использовать механизм:

```
    public interface IWithBreakpoints
    {
        bool EnableBreakpoints { get; set; } // локальный флаг вкл/откл
        int NestingLevel { get; }            // уровень вложенности 
        string GetDebugInfo();               // строка с инфо об объекте
    }
```

Сам `Breakpoints`, отчасти основан на extension-методе-расширении `bool Debug()`, в котором одновременно делается (если надо) вывод инфо в `output` и возвращается флаг необходимости вызова точки останова:

```
    public static class Breakpoints
    {
        public static bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public static bool WritingEnabled { get; set; }

        static Breakpoints()
        {
            Enabled = false;
            WritingEnabled = true;
        }

        public static bool Debug(this IWithBreakpoints @object)
        {
            bool shouldWrite = false;
            bool shouldBreak = false;

#if DEBUG
            shouldWrite = WritingEnabled;
                && @object.EnableBreakpoints
                ;
            shouldBreak = Enabled
                && @object.EnableBreakpoints
                && Debugger.IsAttached
                ;
#endif
            WriteLineIf(shouldWrite, @object.GetDebugInfo(), @object.NestingLevel);
            return shouldBreak;
        }

        // ---------------------------------------------

        // .... реализации WriteLine(..) основанных на Debug.WriteLine(..) 
        // .... с добавлением названия метода и номера строки  
    }
```

---

Если более подробно, то использовать так:

```
    public class TreeItem : IWithBreakpoints
    {
        public string Name { get; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(1,4);

        public TreeItem Parent { get; set; }
        public List<TreeItem> Children { get; } = new List<TreeItem>();

        public TreeItem(TreeItem parent, int childrenCount)
        {
            NestingLevel = parent != null ? parent.NestingLevel + 1 : 0;
            if (this.Debug())
                Debugger.Break();

            Parent = parent ?? null;
            if (childrenCount == 0)
                return;
            for (int i = 0; i <= childrenCount-1; i++ )
            {
                Children.Add(new TreeItem(this, childrenCount - 1));
            }

            if (this.Debug())
                Debugger.Break();
        }

        public void Traverse(Action<TreeItem> action)
        {
            if (this.Debug())
                Debugger.Break();

            action(this);
            foreach(var child in this.Children)
            {
                child.Traverse(action);
            }
        }

        //  --------------------------

        public bool EnableBreakpoints { get; set; } = true;
        public int NestingLevel { get; set; }

        public string GetDebugInfo()
        {
            return $"{Name} (ChildrenCount={Children.Count}): ";
        }
    }
```

И так:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Breakpoints.Enabled = true;
            Breakpoints.WritingEnabled = true;

            Debug.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
            var item = new TreeItem(null, 3);

            Debug.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
            item.Traverse(it => Console.WriteLine(it.Name));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Тогда, остановившись на каждой `Debugger.Break()`, программа выведет в `output` следующие строки:

```
------------------------------------
####  [02:58:59.823]: 0025 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:03.498]: . 95d4 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:04.360]: . . 1136 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:05.321]: . . . d8aa (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:06.152]: . . 1136 (ChildrenCount=1):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 31
####  [02:59:07.056]: . . 2585 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:07.698]: . . . 6b50 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:08.273]: . . 2585 (ChildrenCount=1):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 31
####  [02:59:08.921]: . 95d4 (ChildrenCount=2):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 31
####  [02:59:09.592]: . f608 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:10.140]: . . 1d3e (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:10.720]: . . . 89ca (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:11.300]: . . 1d3e (ChildrenCount=1):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 31
####  [02:59:11.891]: . . 1e46 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:12.554]: . . . b09a (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:13.511]: . . 1e46 (ChildrenCount=1):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 31
####  [02:59:14.314]: . f608 (ChildrenCount=2):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 31
####  [02:59:15.105]: . ce17 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:15.657]: . . 67c2 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:16.129]: . . . a049 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:16.681]: . . 67c2 (ChildrenCount=1):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 31
####  [02:59:17.207]: . . 5827 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:17.681]: . . . 2c55 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 20
####  [02:59:18.144]: . . 5827 (ChildrenCount=1):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 31
####  [02:59:18.777]: . ce17 (ChildrenCount=2):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 31
####  [02:59:19.425]: 0025 (ChildrenCount=3):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem..ctor(TreeItem parent, Int32 childrenCount) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 31
------------------------------------
####  [02:59:23.251]: 0025 (ChildrenCount=3):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:26.377]: . 95d4 (ChildrenCount=2):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:27.407]: . . 1136 (ChildrenCount=1):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:28.081]: . . . d8aa (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:28.865]: . . 2585 (ChildrenCount=1):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:29.591]: . . . 6b50 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:30.298]: . f608 (ChildrenCount=2):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:31.002]: . . 1d3e (ChildrenCount=1):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:31.616]: . . . 89ca (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:32.184]: . . 1e46 (ChildrenCount=1):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:32.867]: . . . b09a (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:33.465]: . ce17 (ChildrenCount=2):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:33.961]: . . 67c2 (ChildrenCount=1):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:34.327]: . . . a049 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:34.617]: . . 5827 (ChildrenCount=1):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
####  [02:59:34.820]: . . . 2c55 (ChildrenCount=0):   #### :       в BreakpointsIdea.TreeItem.Traverse(Action`1 action) в C:\Users\User\source\repos\BreakpointsIdea\BreakpointsIdea\Program.cs:строка 37
```

---

По вопросам:

1. *Существуют наработанные подходы или нет:* не знаю, сходу не нашел.
2. *Какие:* не знаю.
3. *Есть ли какие-нибудь идеи:* то, что в ответе.
4. *Целесообразно ли вообще использовать подобный подход:* думаю, иногда можно.
5. *Целесообразно ли повсеместно закладывать:* не знаю.
6. *Чего не достает*: если таких точек много, то как их лучше отключать, или наоборот, как включать только нужные? Если строку `GetStackTraceLine()` использовать как ключ, то можно было бы организовать временный tmp файл, где хранить флаг включен/отключен для каждой такой точки останова. И менять его при остановке прямо в `Quick-Watch`? По истечении времени чтобы эти точки сами дисэйблились? Или это навороты?

---

`GetStackTraceLine()`:

```
        private static string GetStackTraceLine()
        {
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(Environment.StackTrace))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("."+nameof(Breakpoints)+".")
                        || line.ToLower().Contains(nameof(Environment.StackTrace).ToLower())
                        || line.Contains(nameof(Environment)))
                        continue;
                    else
                        return line;
                }
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

---

Весь код механизма:

```
    public interface IWithBreakpoints
    {
        bool EnableBreakpoints { get; set; }   // локальный флаг включения отключения механизма
        int NestingLevel { get; }              // уровень вложенности 
        string GetDebugInfo();                 // строка с информацией об объекте для вывода
    }

    public static class Breakpoints
    {
        public static bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public static bool WritingEnabled { get; set; }

        static Breakpoints()
        {
            Enabled = false;
            WritingEnabled = true;
        }

        public static bool Debug(this IWithBreakpoints @object)
        {
            bool shouldWrite = false;
            bool shouldBreak = false;

#if DEBUG
            shouldWrite = WritingEnabled;
                && @object.EnableBreakpoints
                ;
            shouldBreak = Enabled
                && @object.EnableBreakpoints
                && Debugger.IsAttached
                ;
#endif
            WriteLineIf(shouldWrite, @object.GetDebugInfo(), @object.NestingLevel);
            return shouldBreak;
        }

        // ---------------------------------------------

        // ....  WriteLine(..) implementations (appends method name and line number from Environment.StackTrace)

        private static string GetStackTraceLine()
        {
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(Environment.StackTrace))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("."+nameof(Breakpoints)+".")
                        || line.ToLower().Contains(nameof(Environment.StackTrace).ToLower())
                        || line.Contains(nameof(Environment)))
                        continue;
                    else
                        return line;
                }
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        private static void WriteLineBase(string line)
        {
            if (WritingEnabled)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);
        }

        private static void WriteLine(string line)
        {
            WriteLine(line, 0);
        }

        private static void WriteLine(string line, int indent)
        {
            var tabs = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++)
            {
                tabs.Append(". ");
            }
            tabs.Append(line);
            WriteLineBase(FormatLine(tabs.ToString()));
        }

        private static void WriteLineIf(bool condition, string line)
        {
            if (condition)
                WriteLine(line, 0);
        }

        private static void WriteLineIf(bool condition, string line, int indent)
        {
            if (condition)
                WriteLine(line, indent);
        }

        private static string ToTimeStringWithMilliseconds(this DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return dateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        private static string FormatLine(string line)
        {
            return $"####  [{DateTime.Now.ToTimeStringWithMilliseconds()}]: {line}  #### :    {GetStackTraceLine()}";
        }

    }
```

И, на всякий, код примера:

```
    public class TreeItem : IWithBreakpoints
    {
        public string Name { get; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(1,4);

        public TreeItem Parent { get; set; }
        public List<TreeItem> Children { get; } = new List<TreeItem>();

        public TreeItem(TreeItem parent, int childrenCount)
        {
            NestingLevel = parent != null ? parent.NestingLevel + 1 : 0;
            if (this.Debug())
                Debugger.Break();

            Parent = parent ?? null;
            if (childrenCount == 0)
                return;
            for (int i = 0; i <= childrenCount-1; i++ )
            {
                Children.Add(new TreeItem(this, childrenCount - 1));
            }

            if (this.Debug())
                Debugger.Break();
        }

        public void Traverse(Action<TreeItem> action)
        {
            if (this.Debug())
                Debugger.Break();

            action(this);
            foreach(var child in this.Children)
            {
                child.Traverse(action);
            }
        }

        //  --------------------------

        public bool EnableBreakpoints { get; set; } = true;
        public int NestingLevel { get; set; }

        public string GetDebugInfo()
        {
            return $"{Name} (ChildrenCount={Children.Count}): ";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Breakpoints.Enabled = true;
            Breakpoints.WritingEnabled = true;

            Debug.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
            var item = new TreeItem(null, 3);

            Debug.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
            item.Traverse(it => Console.WriteLine(it.Name));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

---

**Updates:**

Upd1:

- уточняю, что в данном случае вывод в итоге происходит в окно студии `output`: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line)`.
- пришло еще пару мелких идей по совершенствованию, например: можно было бы вместо того, чтобы для каждого объекта прописывать `IsEnabled`, чтобы у таких объектов был ключ, а потом по ключу прописывать (или хранить) enabled/disabled
- потом прочитал, что лучше использовать pattern-ы *decorator* или *visitor*, спасибо за совет!
- еще то, что методу `this.Debug()` можно было бы сделать перегрузку `this.Debug(string debugInfo)`, которая бы вместо стандартной строки объекта писала бы конкретное сообщение
- еще теоретически можно как-то ловить информацию полного stack-trace по каждой такой точке останова, но тогда нужен какой-то tool.

Comment: прикольно, но не могу сходу придумать кейс, где бы это оказалось полезным, разве что асинхронные методы отлаживать не превращая их невольно в синхронные, но для диагностического вывода есть отладочный логер, который умеет писать в окно вывода студии например.

Comment: Использовать отладочный код с основным плохая затея. Лучше эту ответственность вынести, например используя паттерн Visitor или Decorator. + есть много всяких удобных штук типа DebuggerDisplayAttribute  https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/enhancing-debugging-with-the-debugger-display-attributes
+ можно создать визуализацию https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data?view=vs-2019

Comment: @rdorn, спасибо! Хотел уточнить, что тут и есть вывод в окно вывода студии: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);`.

Comment: @rdorn, Возможно, когда замороченный код, видно не только текущее состояние, но и развитие во времени. StackTrace не всегда показывает интересующую инфо о прежнем каком-то состоянии. Например, когда поспешно нажал очередной раз F5, видно, что было при прошлом останове. Например, когда студия вызывает 2 exe-шника одновременно, и они взаимодействуют между собой (например, wcf). Например, когда много событий одно на другом и рекурсий, можно сбиться с толку, почему здесь оказались. Предполагаю, что может быть когда пишешь код и еще помнишь, о чем идет речь, то прописывать эти точки, потом забудешь

Comment: @rdorn, может быть, когда-нибудь сделаю более симпатичную реализацию идеи, но в примитивном варианте, можно и без вспомогательного инструмента: сначала один раз `Debugger.Launch();`, а потом прописывать точки с каким-нибудь условием `if (localFlag && globalFlag)`, а внутри условия два вызова: `дебаг врайт лайн` и `дебаггер брейк`.

Comment: @SultanovShamil, да, спасибо! вряд ли что-то новое придумал. И за паттерны спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Лично я не представляю себе, где бы мне в реальных сценариях понадобилась глубокая интеграция отладки в код приложения. Кому она может понадобиться? Пользователю у которого на компьютере нет студии? Нужно просто писать приложение хорошо и модульно, не забывать писать юнит-тесты из которых вполне себе доступна не только кнопка Run, но и Debug - и можно провалиться внутрь исполняемого кода и посмотреть вживую, что там происходит.

Подобный уровень интеграции уже есть из коробки и его на компьютере разработчика вполне достаточно.

Я много прототипирую кода в linqpad перед тем, как вносить его в студию и достаточно часто у меня бывает необходимость из кода в linqpad провалиться в код проекта, написанный в студии и продолжить там отладку.

В таком случае мне вполне достаточно добавить одну строку в начале скрипта:

```
//Debugger.Launch();
```